# Call stack error while creating chained store in Ext Classic toolkit

Tags: extjs

I have a chained store which is linked with the main store. I face 'Maximum call stack error' while creating chained store when the source is having more than 127k records.

While I am able to load those many records in source store, is there any limit on items a chained store has?

I looked into documentation and the [source code](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.3.1/classic/src/ChainedStore.js.html) but there is no mention of any limit on data.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce the issue
Fiddle with issue - https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3mr5

While looking at the main code, it populates the items by doing push.apply so that source items will be pushed at flat level

```
onCollectionRefresh: function(source) {
  ..
  items.push.apply(items, sourceItems);
  ..
}
```

Now apply has practical limitations on the limit of arguments it can work with.
On chrome, currently you can pass up to 123427 arguments in an array in apply.

Following code will break in chrome:

```
let data = [];
for(i=0; i<1_23_428; i++){
    data.push({index: i});
}
let a = [];
a.push.apply(a, data)
```

I will suggest having an override which will push the items as is and then use Ext.Array.Flatten, something like below

```
items.push(sourceItems);
items = Ext.Array.flatten(items);
```

While doing so, check the impact on performance for both the ways.

Reference: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply#:~:text=But%20beware%3A%20by,the%20full%20array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply#:%7E:text=But%20beware%3A%20by,the%20full%20array).